# How to run append query from data macro MS Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, linked-tables

I have 2 table, one is local named 'Client' and other is a linked table to MySQL DB in my web-server named 'ClientSql'.
When I insert data into the table `Client`, I want it to be insert into `clientSql` too. I try it with data macro (after insert), but it shows me an error saying

> It's not possible in linked tables.

I have tried to create an append query successfully, and it works, but it just works if I execute it manually. My question is:
Is it possible to call it from a data macro? if is possible, can you show me how? If not, can you point me to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you should be able to do it manually, but not via a macro. According to this link

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html
```

you should be able to do it either way.

Another thought is to eliminate the local access client table and have the access program update the mySql table directly. However, if another program is accessing the client table at the same time, this could become tricky due to multi-user and locking situations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I may not have explained myself well, the query works well, I wanted was an automatic way to run it whenever a line is introduced, I can not remove the local table because several operations are generated in it.
The table ClienteSql only purpose is for web's consultations to a webservice.
is there any other way?

Comment: I always tended to avoid macros, anyway. My preference is to run a VB function. It's easier to debug, for example - you can walk through the code. There are plenty of examples of accessing databases via code on the net. But how will you get it to be triggered automatically?

Comment: I realy don't no, this is my problem, i don't no how to trigger it when a row is inserted in the Client table, i was thinking that maybe it was possible to do it by data macro, because it work well with local tables, but when i tried with linked table..... does n work.... now I'm thinking that my approach is all wrong, and i realy don't now how to do it...  I have to try another approach. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you automatically run a macro when a row is inserted, even if it's just locally? For example, can you run a macro that says, "Hello" when a row is inserted? If your code is structured such that this is possible, then you're not necessarily on the wrong track.

Comment: it let me do some operation, but not show  alert, like send a email, or incert data into local table, data macro as not the same permitions as the simple macro. (i m not sure if it´s call data macro in portugues its call "pos action events").... Now im tring to do the conection and a query with php maybe it will work.... Thanks again, and sorry, i m verry noob in access...

Comment: Good luck - most apps these days are Web-based or mobile anyway, so PHP sounds like a good option.